# ¿como devolver los valores que no encuentra o no estan dentro de un rango de fechas en una consulta en oracle y mostrarlo en php?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Estoy mostrando los datos de una consulta realizada de `Oracle` en `PHP` con una condición entre dos fechas (*por ejemplo del 1-04-2020 al 30-04-2020*)

Hay días en los que no ingresaron información ya sea domingos o festivos, esos días no los devuelve ya que no existen datos

¿Como podría realizar el `SELECT` mostrando esas fechas con valores en `0` o `null` en `PHP`?

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(fecha_pago_d ,'dd-mm-yyyy') as fecha
 ,SUM (DECODE(cd_caja,'caja1',(VALOR_RECAUDO))) caja1
 ,SUM (DECODE(cd_caja,'caja2',(VALOR_RECAUDO))) caja2
 ,SUM (VALOR_RECAUDO) TOTAL_DIA
 FROM   vista_cliente
 WHERE  fecha_pago BETWEEN to_char(to_date('01-04-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'j') AND to_char(to_date('30-04-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'j')
 GROUP BY fecha_pago_d
 ORDER BY 1"
```

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Me gusta usar arreglos y sería buena idea crear uno con cada día del rango como índice. Al recorrer los resultados llenas el día correspondiente y, al final, muestras los datos desde el arreglo.

Comment: como se podria usar? ya que no se como y estoy un poco novato con eso por favor si se puede :)

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código con el que lees la consulta y muestras los datos.

Comment: agrego yo el codigo? o es para que usted pueda agregar ?, disculpe